# Vue router fails after build

Tags: vue.js

I developed an application in vue 3.10.0 with a template downloaded from Vue official website. Works well when run with npm run serve but after build, browser window is blank. Build is successful and no errors in console

I have changed the public path in the vue config file to where it's been loaded on the server.

The config file looks like this:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";

module.exports = {
  publicPath: isProd ? "/facil-users/" : "",
  //publicPath: isProd ? "" : "",
  configureWebpack: {
    // Set up all the aliases we use in our app.
    plugins: [
      new webpack.optimize.LimitChunkCountPlugin({
        maxChunks: 6
      })
    ]
  },
  pwa: {
    name: 'Facil app',
    themeColor: '#172b4d',
    msTileColor: '#172b4d',
    appleMobileWebAppCapable: 'yes',
    appleMobileWebAppStatusBarStyle: '#172b4d'
  },
  css: {
    // Enable CSS source maps.
    sourceMap: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
  }
};
```

Route file looks like this:

```
const routes = [{
    path: '/',
    redirect: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardLayout,
    children: [{
        path: '/dashboard',
        name: 'dashboard',
        component: () => import('./views/Dashboard.vue'),
        meta: {
          requiresAuth: true
        }
      },
      {
        path: '/user',
        name: 'single user',
        component: () => import('./views/users/ViewSingleUser.vue'),
        meta: {
          requiresAuth: true
        }
      },
      {
        path: '/users',
        name: 'users',
        component: () => import('./views/users/ViewUsers.vue'),
        meta: {
          requiresAuth: true
        }
      },
      {
        path: '/profile',
        name: 'profile',
        component: () => import('./views/users/UserProfile.vue'),
        meta: {
          requiresAuth: true
        }
      },
      {
        path: '/register-user',
        name: 'regiseter user',
        component: () => import('./views/authentication/NewRegistration.vue'),
        meta: {
          //isAdmin: true,
          requiresAuth: true
        }
      },
    ]
  },

]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: routes
});
```

I ought to have the view responding just like i have it when i do an npm run serve. Access from localhost/facil-users/ returns a black screen, i have also added the .htaccess code as suggested on the vue official website.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you replicate somewhere? maybe in codesandbox.com

Comment: Hello Onwuka. Are you referring to replicating the whole project content before build or the content of the dist folder after build on codesandbox.com?

Comment: I disabled the history mode in the router config and it works now but i'll like it to work with the history mode. Thanks